# Euler's Formula for 1-planar graphs

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Does Euler's Formula hold for [1-planar graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-planar_graph)? I've tested it for a couple of graphs and the result was $3$ instead of $2$.

> Given a connected $1$-planar Graph $G=(V,E)$, with $n$ nodes, $e$ edges and $f$ faces. Does the following hold:
>
> $$n - e + f = 3$$

I have not found any literature mentioning Euler's Formula in the context of $1$-planar graphs.

EDIT (copied from one of the comments): "A graph is called $1$-planar if it can be drawn in the plane so that each its edge is crossed by at most one other edge."

Comment: If two edges cross, how do you define a "face"?

Comment: What do you count as a "face" in this case?

Comment: G partitions the plane into several regions, called faces (plus the outer region/face). In short: The faces of a planar graph are the areas which are surrounded by edges.Does the intersection of two edges possibly lead to more faces without violating that definition?

Comment: It would be better to include a definition of $1$-planar, rather than a link.

Comment: @Ubuntix: *"The faces of a planar graph are the areas which are surrounded by edges."* ... umm ... When edges of a $1$-planar graph cross, they create regions that are not surrounded by *edges*, but rather (at least partially) by "half-edges"; moreover, those regions have "corners" that do not correspond to vertices of the graph. This kind of thing throws-off standard counting arguments. Perhaps one can formulate an Euler-like result incorporating these features, but it would probably need to replace "$e$" with, say, "$e_0$" and "$e_1$" where "$e_i$" is the number of edges with $i$ crossings.

Comment: @Blue Now that makes sence, I've cleary missunderstood that definition.

Comment: @Ubuntix: Thinking out loud ... Let $1$-planar graph $G$ have $v$ vertices, $e_0$ non-crossing edges, and $e_1$ crossers. Define $G'$ as the "apparent" planar counterpart of $G$. "Apparent vertices" are actual vertices, along with edge crossings; $v'=v+\tfrac12e_1$. "Apparent edges" are non-crossing edges, along with halves of the crossing edges: $e'=e_0+2e_1$. "Apparent faces" are regions fully bounded by complete edges (say, $f_0$), and those that aren't ($f_1$); so, $f'=f_0+f_1$. Apparent elements satisfy $v'-e'+f'=2$, so (barring on-the-fly errors) we'd have $$v-e_0-\tfrac32e_1+f_0+f_1=2$$

Comment: It seems to be true, at least for my examples. Looking interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess regarding how one might define faces might be useful *if* you took each pair of points in $G$ that form an overcrossing/undercrossing, and then squish those two points together to form a single new node, thereby converting $G$ into an ordinary planar graph (although changing the count of nodes and edges).

But since you are *not* squishing those two points together, there's no expectation of any nice formula.

It turns out that there are correct generalizations of Euler's formula, involving some more advanced topology. One such generalization, still comewhat close to Euler's formula for a planar graph, is the [Euler characteristic of a surface](http://euler%20characteristic%20riemann%20surface).

Comment: So basically, the definition of faces is wrong in my case? "The faces of a planar graph are the areas which are surrounded by edges". Can't I have an area surrounded by edges without the intersection of two edges forming a vertex?

Comment: A so-called "1-planar graph" is not a planar graph. It is embedded in 3-dimensional space, but it is not embedded in the plane.

Comment: Two edges of a 1-planar graph which form an overcrossing/undercrossing pair *do not intersect* each other.

Comment: Well, that's the first time I hear that to be honest. Can you provide literature? In "The structure of 1-planar graphs" by Fabrici and Madaras it is clearly stated that a 1-planar graph is embedded in the plane. Furthermore, in "Recognizing outer 1-planar graphs in linear time" by Auer et. al. it is even stated that every outer 1-planar graph is planar, whereby an outer 1-planar graph is both: a combination of 1-planarity and outerplanarity. It is also defined as an embedding in the plane.

Comment: Can you give a full citation of that paper by Fabrici and Madaras, together with the statement that a 1-planar graph is embedded in the plane?

Comment: You can find it right here: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2005.11.056

Comment: It is stated, that "A graph is called 1-planar if it can be drawn in the plane so that each its edge is crossed by at most one other edge".

Comment: A "drawing in the plane" is not an embedding of the graph if the drawn images of  two edges cross each other.

Comment: @LeeMosher: It appears that $1$-planar graphs are considered "embedded" in the plane, with edge-crossings *allowed* but not counted as vertices. The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-planar_graph) says (**emphasis** mine) "If a 1-planar graph [...] is drawn that way, the drawing is called a [...] 1-planar **embedding** of the graph". (In my mind, "embedding" here is something of an abuse of terminology. I'll note that I've not heard of $1$-planar graphs before I saw this question.)

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I've missunderstood the term "embedding". I'll do more research about that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifiying!

Comment: Indeed, I agree this is an abuse of terminology, but it is a tolerable abuse if you keep in mind that a "1-planar embedding" is not the same thing as an "embedding".

Comment: Very glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Converting comments to an answer ...

First, we note that the notion of "face" for a $1$-planar graph is problematic. When edges of a $1$-planar graph cross, they create regions that are not surrounded by edges, but rather (at least partially) by "half-edges"; moreover, those regions have "corners" that do not correspond to vertices of the graph. This kind of thing throws-off standard counting arguments. Nevertheless, we *can* formulate an Euler-like result as follows:

Let $1$-planar graph $G$ have $v$ vertices, $e_0$ non-crossing edges, and $e_1$ crossers. (Note that $e_0$ and $e_1$ are features of a *particular drawing* of the graph. It may be possible to draw $G$ with fewer (or more) crossing edges.) Define $G'$ as the "apparent" planar counterpart of $G$ based on the particular drawing of $G$.

- "Apparent vertices" are actual vertices, along with edge-crossings (one for every two crossing edges): 
  $$v′=v+\tfrac12 e_1 \tag{1}$$
- "Apparent edges" are non-crossing edges, along with "halves" of the crossing edges: 
  $$e' = e_0+2e_1 \tag{2}$$
- "Apparent faces" are planar regions fully bounded by complete edges (say, $f_0$), along with those that aren't ($f_1$).
  $$f'=f_0+f_1 \tag{3}$$

Apparent elements satisfy Euler's formula:
$$ v'−e'+f'=2 \tag{4}$$
so that we have

> $$v−e_0−\tfrac32e_1+f_0+f_1=2 \tag{$\star$}$$

As a sanity check, consider this $1$-planar graph:

[image]

(Image credit: [David Eppstein](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:3-crossing_Heawood_graph.svg), via Wikipedia's ["$1$-planar graph" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-planar_graph).)

Here, we have $v = 14$, $e_0 = 15$, $e_1 = 6$, $f_0 = 0$, $f_1 = 12$, which satisfy $(\star)$.